# Could not initialize SDL : No available video device Don't move

Tags: 12.04, games, sdl

I have downloaded an indie game **`Don't move`** from this [link](http://www.indiedb.com/games/dont-move/downloads/dont-move-v12-linux) . When I try to run it on Ubuntu 12.04, it gives following error messages.

`Could not initialize SDL : No available video device
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed`

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The description says: Don't Move version 1.2 for Linux. Please note that this version is untested, if you have any problems let me know.

Answer (score 7):

For me, SDL2-2.0.3 was used.
-> Had trouble with no video driver found.
typed

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

did another `./configure` and it reported this

```
Assembly Math   : mmx 3dnow sse sse2
Audio drivers   : disk dummy oss
Video drivers   : dummy x11(dynamic) opengl
X11 libraries   : xcursor xinerama xinput2 xinput2_multitouch xrandr xscrnsaver xshape xvidmode
Input drivers   : linuxev linuxkd
Using libudev   : YES
Using dbus      : NO
```

It went through everything fine but the test folder after trying to make the code it reported "Missing -lGL" 
so I just assumed it was missing mesa or something and I did this

```
sudo apt-get build-dep xscreensaver
sudo apt-get source xscreensaver -b
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

I force installed the popular xscreensaver with my own build and SDL worked.  The idea was if I could compile the screensaver then I can get SDL working.
Thanks. Worked for me. (video only)
tried to run testmultiaudio and got this

```
INFO: Using audio driver: dsp
ERROR: Don't see any specific audio devices!
```

I guess compiling and making VLC would solve most of this because VLC uses SDL for video and audio.

The counter idea is ncurses 5.9 works just fine.

Honestly, I was using peppermint 6 which was build from ubuntu and debian.  I assume it works on that OS too.  That is why I am posting in piecemeal steps... VLC compiling.... ERROR.  Trying to do the same with totem.
(while compiling totem)
Maybe I should make a scroller demo to my imaginary friends in ncurses "BranMuffin" "Cerealbowl"  "Cornflakes" and a "bowl full of cherries"

new SDL2-2.3 configure report

```
Assembly Math   : mmx 3dnow sse sse2
Audio drivers   : disk dummy oss alsa(dynamic) pulse(dynamic)
Video drivers   : dummy x11(dynamic) opengl opengl_es2
X11 libraries   : xcursor xinerama xinput2 xinput2_multitouch xrandr xscrnsaver xshape xvidmode
Input drivers   : linuxev linuxkd
Using libudev   : YES
Using dbus      : YES
```

another round of ./configure make make install on SDL
another round of ./configure make and ./testmultiaudio and BINGO I have it after I built and installed totem too
so somewhere in the chaotic view of things from VLC and `sudo apt-get build-dep totem | sudo apt-get source totem -b | dpkg -i *deb` ... I got my audio and video now.

References: [this page] and [SDL install](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation) and [compiling](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/linux/cli/index.php)
remember to test if you can compile it yourself.

..to sum it up on another machine and it got it working (not the best way because I am a C average guy)

1. get SDL2-2.3 from libsdl site
2. get some packages and compile some.  I believe that VLC and XSCREENSAVER are the only packages that are needed VLC for SDL and audio and XSCREENSAVER for opengl

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
   sudo apt-get build-dep xscreensaver vlc totem
   sudo apt-get source xscreensaver totem -b
   ```
3. (2.5) might as well get `xscreensaver` and totem freshly built and install the .deb packages
4. unpack SDL and go into the folder and do the common

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   cd test
   ./configure
   make
   ./testmultiaudio
   ```
5. enjoy audio clip

OS USED peppermint linux but I assume that even debian, linux mint, and ubuntu would work.

Comment: @muru: I was doing the exact same thing...   You beat me to it... Voted "looks OK".  ;-)  (Now!)

Answer (score 3):

This did work for me on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's related to the SDL, try to install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

It should solve your problem accessing the video device.